# Animate view and stop midway

Tags: ios, swift, animation, caanimation

I want to make a view/header collaspe/expand animation, but I also want to be able to pause or stop from expanding/collapsing while the user takes his finger off the screen.

I have a current implementation for this, but the animation is not very smooth.

I will also add some images to explain better what I want to do.

So the first image is how it should look when expanded.

The second image is how it should look if the user decides to take take his finger off the screen while he would scroll slowly so the animation/the view should stop in a state similar to that.

The third image is how it should look when it is collapsed.

If someone has any recommendation how I could achieve this I would be very grateful.

[image: expanded]

[image: mid expanded]

[image: collapsed]

Comment: show the code that you already have

Comment: The code that I already have needs to be completly replaced. It was made by another developer and it was generated by some tool. I want to do it from scratch

Answer (score 2):

If you are targeting iOS 10+, use [`UIViewPropertyAnimator`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator) which encapsulates an animation and allows scrubbing and controlling the animation:

> Start, pause, resume, and stop animations; see the methods of the `UIViewAnimating` protocol.
>
> Add animation blocks after the original animations start using the `addAnimations(_:)` and `addAnimations(_:delayFactor:)` methods.
>
> Scrub through a paused animation by modifying the `fractionComplete` property.
>
> Change the animation’s direction using the `isReversed` property.
>
> Modify the timing and duration of a partially complete animation by pausing the animation and using the `continueAnimation(withTimingParameters:durationFactor:)` method to finish it.

You just need to wire up touches to `UIViewPropertyAnimator` object encapsulating the animation.

There are many good tutorials on how to start with it, e.g. [this one](https://medium.com/@daniel_larsson/interactive-animations-with-uiviewpropertyanimator-284580951c62).

Comment: I tought about using this and just looked at the wwdc video about this, but I am not sure if I can make the view stay in the state like in the second picture if the user takes his finger away from the screen. Won't the view go to the completly expanded/collapsed state when his finger is not on the screen anymore?

Comment: @razvan that depends on how you implement it.. this is the way to go I believe.. of course you will have to handle the cases and define how you want it to behave, but `UIViewPropertyAnimator` will allow you to do so

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try it using UIViewPropertyAnimator